# why GPU is often many frames behind the CPU?

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, game-engine, directx-11

In Directx 11 documentation I saw an statement in this link [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d11/ne-d3d11-d3d11_map) which stated GPU is often many frames behind the CPU.

It looks strange to me suppose I am playing a shooter game and I make a perfect headshot, the game can consider it a miss because what I'm seeing is some frames before the actual frame and when application is testing where I have shot, objects positions might have changed which makes the game inaccurate if it's not a design choice.

My question is when this situation(i.e. gpu stays behind cpu) happens, is it frequent, how many frames it can be behind and is there anyway to guarantee gpu and cpu work on the same frame?(I'm talking about directx 11)

Comment: When the GPU is still working on frames that are a few frames behind the CPU, then the game is said to be "GPU bound" and this is the desirable situation. This scenario should not lead to game logic on the CPU (e.g. hit detection) being applied to the wrong frame.
The alternative scenario (i.e. a CPU-bound game) where the GPU is idle as it waits for the CPU to provide it work, is what must be avoided, as this leads to slow frame rates.

Comment: From the link: "Keeping track of which sections of a resource are being used because of calls made 2 to 5 frames ago is difficult and error-prone.". Presumably 0 and 1 frames ago are also possible, but less difficult to handle. The CPU will be 0-5 frames ahead. Don;t forget your eyes and brain and hand also take time to determine things

Comment: And what is the relation to programming and SO?

Comment: There is a simple solution: Predict, what the players will do/could do in 5 frames or a second or two and show that. They will ever be grateful for such instantaneous graphics. ;-)